# Databinding in the second tabitem does not work

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF TabControl with two TabItems. In both tabItems I have a textbox with the Text property bound to a property in my ViewModel. The problem is that the binding in the second tab (the one "hidden" by the first tab) is not working. I have two cases:

- I run the app, I run the command that would fill the text in the second tab, I select the tab: in this case the binding works: I can see the textbox filled with data. But if I run again the command the textbox does not get updated anymore. It looks like the binding works, but only once.
- The second case is if I run the app, and then, before running the command, I select the second tab. In this case the binding does not work at all.

If I move the second tab to the first position, then the binding will work for this tab. (but it will stop working for the other one)

Does someone knows about a worksround for that

Comment: It would help to see your bindings in XAML; can you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ViewModel has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.
Also you have to set the UpdateSourceTrigger property of your binding to "PropertyChanged". After this changes your app should working as expected.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I had to add the UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged".